# Queue undefined when concatenating JS files with Gulp

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gulp, concatenation

I have the following Gulp task:

```
// compile and combine javascript
gulp.task('combine-js', function () {
    return gulp.src(['public/src/js/d3.min.js', 'public/src/js/queue.min.js', 'public/src/js/topojson.js', 'public/src/js/draw-map.js'])
        .pipe(concat('custom.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + '/js'));
});
```

And have the following code in `draw-map.js`:

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, '../data/mpaths.json')
.defer(d3.csv, '../data/metric.csv', function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); }).await(ready);
```

Based on [this tutorial](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) from Mike Bostock, I am loading the JS files in the correct order

1. D3
2. Queue
3. TopoJSON

Yet I get this:

[image: queue is not defined]

What am I doing wrong? I did a `Find` via Chrome Dev tools in the resulting `custom.js` and did find that the `queue` library is present!

Comment: Are you sure the queue.js you importing via gulp same as //d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js

Comment: erm, not it is probably not, but would that matter? the `defer` and `await` methods are all I'm using and from the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue), I can see that these two methods still exist!

Comment: try this d3.queue() instead of queue() as shown in the https://github.com/d3/d3-queue

Comment: Good catch @Cyril, sadly I now get `d3.queue is not defined`, I restarted my server and ran gulp again to be sure